# Starting audiodg.exe with a different affinity in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch

I have tried to set that to "high" with no luck:

```
wmic process where (name like="audiodg.exe") CALL setpriority "high"
```

The only command I can find that will set the affinity is:

```
start /affinity 1 program.exe
```

The problem is that I cannot terminate the old "audiodg.exe" and start a new one even with wait time between calls. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my current code:

```
wmic process where name="audiodg.exe" CALL terminate
start /affinity 1 audiodg.exe
wmic process where name="audiodg.exe" CALL setpriority "above normal"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Not affiliated but I ran into this need myself, and found a tool that does this automatically in case you're OK for a separate tool, Process Lasso by Bitsum: https://bitsum.com/

It lets you set `audiodg.exe`'s affinity / priority at realtime, led to the tool from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71HrZfR_Fro&list=WL

Comment: Welcome to Super User.   Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/150988) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software.  You should provide some additional information about the software itself, showing how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.